# Finding the angles of two projectiles with the same range

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

If two parabolic paths have the same range and I know the angle of one of them, can I calculate the other angle?

My professor says this is the formula to calculate the angle, but I only get one angle out of it, idk how to find the other.
$$sin(2θ)=gx^*/v^2$$ where $x^*$ is the point where they meet.

[image: It is something like this but I only know the velocity of one of them]

This is an example of what i'm talking about, but in my case I only know the angle and velocity of the first parabolic path

Comment: Welcome to physics stackexchange. Your question is unclear. What information do you have for the second trajectory, where you intend to find the angle? The distance is given, fair enough, but we need one more piece of information, like the initial velocity (maybe equal to the one from the first trajectory?).

Comment: The person below said that the second angle is $180-x$ with x being the first. I'm looking for something like this just the angle

Comment: As I said above, you need to give information. If you can calculate the angle from initial velocity and distance travelled, and you only say that the distance travelled is given, what do you expect?

Comment: Well actually I only said the velocity and angle of the second path are not given. The velocity and angle of the first are well known so if we know that they have the same range maybe I can calculate the angle( also I'm working in polar coordinates)

Comment: I think the polar coordinates are my problem because for example the angle $π/4$ and $5π/4$ have the same range.

Comment: if you throw projectile at a higher angle and need the same range then you would need to throw it at higher velocity than the first so when you find the other angle(180-x) and equate with formula of range(you know the range as by 1st projectile) you will get different velocity and in the end they both will come same

Comment: If the magnitude of the velocity of the second projectile is not known there are infinitely many pairs of angles and velocities which will result in the same range. Not just another one.

Comment: You are right, If the projectiles have the same velocity, then I can find the other angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've understood, we need more parameters to find the angle.

As it is clear from the formula that
$$\frac{v^{2}sin2{\theta}}{g} = R$$

If you keep $R$ constant, then $\theta$ and $v$ are free to move. They can take any value to keep the range constant.

If you know the launch velocity, you can certainly calculate $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can calculate the angle of 2nd path

in your case x* is point where they meet(it is the range)

Your professor gave you the formula for calculating range which can be written as:

$v^2Sin2Q\over g$ = x* (Here Q = theeta I dont know how to write it)

So, **1 projectile** is thrown at an angle of *x* , *velocity $v_1$* and another projectile is thrown at angle *Q* , *velocity $v_2$* and they both cover the same **range R**

you can equate both the ranges and will be left with:

$v_1^2$Sin2x = $v_2^2$Sin2Q (g in denominator will get cancelled)

so you can easily find unknown angle(let it be Q) if you know the $v_1$ , $v_2$ and angle x

Comment: Yes, what you're saying is correct, but in my case, I don't know neither the velocity nor the angle of the second path. I thought maybe I can find it with some kind of symmetry or something like that.

Comment: @Randomdude You can calculate the angle as range is a function of sine so it will repeat it's value after a interval so for example if one angle is $x$ then the other angle will be (180-x) and you know the angle you can calculate the velocity :)

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid, but if for example my angle is 75 degrees then the other angle would be 105? Because an angle of 105 wouldn't have the same range.

Comment: @Randomdude it should have the same range because the velocity will also change according to the angle. 
Try it yourself for eg: take velocity and angle for any 1 path then calculate the range, and for second path you can get the angle(180-x) and you will get velocity corresponding to that angle so that both the path will have same range :)

Comment: Play around with [this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/znsv7pz3). You'll realise that you need $v$ to find the angle exactly.